# Alert error but details saved in database

Tags: javascript

When I press submit, it would display "Cannot save user" error. However, the details were all able to be saved into the database. Not sure what went wrong but it should have displayed "user saved" and directing user to *homepage_admin.php* instead due to it being saved into the database. I tried to inspect for error, however there was nothing.

```
$().ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    var userid;                   
    var password;          
    var passwordagain;    
    var firstname;
    var lastname;
    var position;


    $("#NewAdminForm").validate({
        rules: {
            txtNewLogin: "required",
            txtNewPassword: "required",
            //the user enters the same value for username and password
            txtNewPasswordAgain: {
                equalTo: "#txtNewPassword"
            },
            txtFirstName: "required",
            txtLastName: "required",
            txtNewPosition: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            txtNewLogin: "new user name is required",
            txtNewPassword: "new password is required",
            txtNewPasswordAgain: "new password again is required and must be the same as new password",
            txtFirstName: "First Name is required",
            txtLastName: "Last Name is required",
            txtNewPosition: "Position is required"
        },
        focusInvalid: false,
        submitHandler: function () {
            return false;
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().after());
        },
    });


    $("#btnCreateAccount").bind("click", function () {
        if ($("#NewAdminForm").valid())
        savenewuser();
    });
});

function savenewuser() {
    if ($("#NewAdminForm").valid())

    userid = $("#txtNewLogin").val();  
    password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();              
    firstname = $("#txtFirstName").val();
    lastname = $("#txtLastName").val();
    position = $("#txtNewPosition").val();

    var url = serverURL() + "/newadmin.php";
    var JSONObject = {
        "userid": userid,
        "password": password,
        "firstname": firstname,
        "lastname": lastname,
        "position": position
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: JSONObject,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (arr) {
            _getNewUserResult(arr);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}

function _getNewUserResult(arr) {
    if (arr[0].result === 1) { //newuser.php accepts this newuser 
        localStorage.setItem("userid", userid);
        localStorage.setItem("password", password);
        localStorage.setItem("firstname", firstname);
        localStorage.setItem("lastname", lastname);
        localStorage.setItem("position", position);
        alert("user saved");
        window.location = "homepage_admin.php";
    }
    else {
        alert("Cannot save user");
    }
}
```

added html

```
        <form class="NewAdminForm" id="NewAdminForm" action="">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <label for="userid">User ID</label>
                <input type="text" name="txtNewLogin" id="txtNewLogin" placeholder="enter user ID" value="peter" required><br/>
            </div>

            <div><label for="password">Password</label>
                 <input type="text" name="txtNewPassword" id="txtNewPassword" placeholder="enter password" value="peter" required><br/></div>

            <div>
                <label for="txtNewPasswordAgain">Re-enter password</label>
                <input type="text" name="txtNewPasswordAgain" id="txtNewPasswordAgain" placeholder="enter password again" value="peter" required><br/>
            </div>

            <div><label for="employeename">Name</label>
                 <input type="text" name="txtNewName" id="txtNewName" placeholder="enter name" value="peter parker" required><br/></div>

            <div><label for="role">Position</label>
                 <input type="text" name="txtNewRole" id="txtNewRole" placeholder="enter position" value="spider man" required><br/></div>

            <br />

            <div><input type="submit" id="btnCreateAccount" value="Create Account"></div>

            <br/>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try checking the value of `arr` that you pass to `_getNewUserResult` function, the result set might be different than what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

1. First check if arr[0].result really returns 1 by:
   after success of ajax request `alert(arr[0].result);` or in _getNewUserResult function.
2. if it shows 1 then instead of arr[0].result === 1
   do
   `arr[0].result ==='1'` or try `arr[0].result ==1`

Comment: can you share url file contents? so that we can help more appropriately

Comment: Hi I've added in the html